# uiwebview random crash

Tags: uiwebview, crash

I have a random crash in uiwebview when I click the link in the website. It is hard to reproduce it. Can anyone can give me some advice, I will be very appreciative; this is the crash log:

```
0 WebCore 0x31398d92 WebCore::toDynamicFrame(JSC::ExecState*) (in WebCore) + 10
1 WebCore 0x31398d12 WebCore::ScriptController::processingUserGesture() (in WebCore) + 26
2 WebCore 0x3152f6fa WebCore::DOMWindow::allowPopUp(WebCore::Frame*) (in WebCore) + 10
3 WebCore 0x31555cc2 WebCore::FrameLoader::submitForm(WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 222
4 WebCore 0x31586fec WebCore::HTMLFormElement::submit(WebCore::Event*, bool, bool, WebCore::FormSubmissionTrigger) (in WebCore) + 272
5 WebCore 0x315874f0 WebCore::HTMLFormElement::prepareForSubmission(WebCore::Event*) (in WebCore) + 188
6 WebCore 0x3157ef72 WebCore::HTMLButtonElement::defaultEventHandler(WebCore::Event*) (in WebCore) + 58
7 WebCore 0x312401fc WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 748
8 WebCore 0x3123fee6 WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const (in WebCore) + 30
9 WebCore 0x3123feba WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WebCore::EventDispatchMediator const&) (in WebCore) + 98
10 WebCore 0x3123fe12 WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 34
11 WebCore 0x31240f82 WebCore::ScopedEventQueue::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr) const (in WebCore) + 38
12 WebCore 0x31240f22 WebCore::ScopedEventQueue::enqueueEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 142
13 WebCore 0x31240e3e WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchScopedEvent(WebCore::Node*, WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 166
14 WebCore 0x31240c8e WebCore::Node::dispatchUIEvent(WTF::AtomicString const&, int, WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 178
15 WebCore 0x3124095c WebCore::Node::defaultEventHandler(WebCore::Event*) (in WebCore) + 112
16 WebCore 0x312401d4 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr) (in WebCore) + 708
17 WebCore 0x313c3902 WebCore::MouseEventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const (in WebCore) + 150
18 WebCore 0x3123feba WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WebCore::EventDispatchMediator const&) (in WebCore) + 98
19 WebCore 0x313c343e WebCore::Node::dispatchMouseEvent(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&, WTF::AtomicString const&, int, WebCore::Node*) (in WebCore) + 90
20 WebCore 0x313c2e32 WebCore::EventHandler::dispatchMouseEvent(WTF::AtomicString const&, WebCore::Node*, bool, int, WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&, bool) (in WebCore) + 66
21 WebCore 0x31541452 WebCore::EventHandler::handleMouseReleaseEvent(WebCore::PlatformMouseEvent const&) (in WebCore) + 750
22 WebCore 0x31542cbe WebCore::EventHandler::mouseUp(WebEvent*) (in WebCore) + 130
23 WebKit 0x376dd2b6 -[WebHTMLView mouseUp:] (in WebKit) + 106
24 WebCore 0x314203c2 -[WAKView _handleEvent:] (in WebCore) + 138
25 WebCore 0x31420332 eventCallback(WKView*, WebEvent*, void*) (in WebCore) + 26
26 WebCore 0x314202d8 _WKViewHandleEvent (in WebCore) + 28
27 WebCore 0x3142004e WKWindowSendEvent (in WebCore) + 242
28 WebCore 0x311d86e2 _WebThreadRun (in WebCore) + 378
29 WebCore 0x318b4ebe -[WAKWindow sendEvent:] (in WebCore) + 70
30 UIKit 0x30eb6c9e __47-[UIWebDocumentView(Interaction) performClick:]_block_invoke_0 (in UIKit) + 590
31 WebCore 0x311d86e2 _WebThreadRun (in WebCore) + 378
32 UIKit 0x30eb6a4a -[UIWebDocumentView(Interaction) performClick:] (in UIKit) + 62
33 UIKit 0x30eb6eda __64-[UIWebDocumentView(Interaction) _sendMouseMoveAndAttemptClick:]_block_invoke_0 (in UIKit) + 274
34 WebCore 0x312280b4 HandleRunSource (in WebCore) + 364
35 CoreFoundation 0x37e71ad2 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 14
36 CoreFoundation 0x37e71334 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 (in CoreFoundation) + 364
37 CoreFoundation 0x37e70044 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 652
38 CoreFoundation 0x37df34a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 300
39 CoreFoundation 0x37df336c CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 104
40 WebCore 0x3127bca2 RunWebThread(void*) (in WebCore) + 402
41 libsystem_c.dylib 0x33050734 _pthread_start (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 320
```